# MongoDB - retrive object from an array of objects from an array of objects. Using Mongoose

Tags: arrays, mongodb, object, mongoose, collections

The title might be wrong, I am a bit confused.

The screen below shows the schema that I am using.
A group consists of a teacher and students. Each group has many quizzes and each quiz has many questions.

[image: Schema]

I am trying to retrieve only 1 quiz(and all of its questions) with the quizzes _id.
I am doing this so I can allow users to create questions for a specific quiz in a group.

So, I tried to retrieve it in two ways. Both ways I end up with all quizzes, with all questions.
quiz and quiz2

[image: Mongoose commands]

This is the output. Both commands have the same output

[image: Mongoose output]

This is the input from the postman

[image: Postman input]

Any help is good,
Thanks in advance

EDIT:
J.F. helped me with the above problem.
What I need help with now:
Adding questions to the quizzes array of objects. 
Schema stays the same. 
 What I tried:

[image: Addding questions to quiz]

The last one isn't finished but it didn't work so I figured I would just stop and ask for help. The postman input is the same as above.

Comment: Using `$elemMatch` into projection should works, check [here](https://mongoplayground.net/p/os6LbiEw75O). Also try using: `groupsModel.findOne({"_id": groupId},{"quizzes": {"$elemMatch": {"_id": quizId}}})` because in your second query you are not using `$elemMatch` into projection stage but in query stage.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both queries are incorrect to get the values.

You have to use projection to get desired values. When you do a query you can use two objects:

```
findOne({query}, {projection})
```

No, why your code doesn't work:

First one: Using mongoose the correct syntax to get the projection is using `select` so this can work:

```js
await model.findOne({id:groupId}).select({"quizzes": {
    "$elemMatch": {
      "id": quizId
    }
  }})
```

Second one: Using mongo query you have to use [`$elemMatch`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/projection/elemMatch/) into projection stage in this way:

```js
model.find({
  "_id": groupId
},
{
  "quizzes": {
    "$elemMatch": {
      "_id": quizId
    }
  }
})
```

Example [here](https://mongoplayground.net/p/os6LbiEw75O)

**EDIT**

To update the desired field into an array you have to use [`positional operator`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/positional/) which is defined as:

> The positional $ operator identifies an element in an array to update without explicitly specifying the position of the element in the array.

So you have to find the array you want to update and push with the positional operator like this:

```
db.collection.update({
  "_id": 1,
  "quizzes._id": 1
},
{
  "$push": {
    "quizzes.$.questions": {
      // your object
    }
  }
})
```

Note that, update query has two objects: `update({obj1}, {obj2})`.

First object is the query to find where update. In this case I want to update the quizz with _id 1.

Find object has found one document, so, into update object we are telling mongo using `quizzes.$.questions`: The quizz you have found update questions field pushing the object.

Example [here](https://mongoplayground.net/p/ah7TBoMQlp4)

Using mongoose is as simple as use the same query like this:

```
var update = await model.updateOne({
    "_id": groupId,
    "quizzes._id": quizId
  },
  {
    "$push": {
      "quizzes.$.questions": {
        // your fields
      }
    }
  })
```

Comment: That helped, thanks a lot. I'm now trying to insert questions into the quizzes. Could you help me with that? I tried to do it on my own today but I failed. I will post the code of the ways that I tried on the bottom of the question. If you can, let me know what I'm doing wrong and how to fix it. Thank you.

Comment: That's me added an edit at the bottom. If you find time - create a new answer. It's hard to read comments.

Comment: I will try it later today. Thank you very much

Comment: All worked perfectly, thank you again. Also, I really appreciate your explanations. Cheers.